# Use AGPS functionality with Arduino and GPS module

Tags: programming, gps

Recently, we developed the UTRAQ L100 GNSS Module base board for testing all the capabilities of the GPS receiver.

*https://www.elementzonline.com/blog/utraq-gps-l100-module-based-on-irnss-supported-by-gagan-navic*

But we couldn't find a way to use the AGPS functionality. Is there any AGPS server available that can be used to download the satellite ephemeris data and feed that to the GPS module?

I got a reference that uses Skytraq AGPS, but not sure if the same is applicable for all receivers with AGPS functionality.

https://github.com/r0ro/skytraq

The above reference uses python code, but hopefully, it can be ported to an Arduino library if the functionality actually works well.